# PHP preg_match using RegEx to match a word

Tags: php, regex

I want to find all the demo words using PHP and regEx.

```
$input ='demo';
$pattern = ''; //$input can be used along with regex, please help here 
$text = 'This is dem*#o text, contains de12mo3 text, is .demo23* text' 

if(preg_match($pattern, $text))
{
 echo 'found';
}else{
 echo'not found';
}
```

the search word `demo` in the `text` may be present in the following format

```
1) may start with special characters/numbers Eg. "12*demo"
2) may contain special characters/numbers within the word Eg.  "de12*mo"
3) may end with special characters/numbers Eg. "demo12*"
```

please help I am stuck,
thanks in advance!

Note: `The $input can be max. of 15 in length`

Comment: @PhpMyCoder I am new to RegEx, this is what I am trying `/[\W$demo\W]/` ,but problem is, it is not able to detect special characters present within word Eg. `de123*#`

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: @pcdhan Good that you tried something, make sure to put it in the question next time.

Comment: @AlexLunix, my mistake, will not repeat next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The Solution

I would start by removing all special characters and numbers from the string, and then matching the word using word boundaries:

```
$cleaned = preg_replace('/[^a-z ]+/i', '', 'This is dem*#o text, contains de12mo3 text, is .demo23* text');

preg_match_all('/\bdemo\b/i', $cleaned, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

var_dump($matches);
```

Will give you ([Codepad Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/iaAaZB)):

```
array(1) {
  [0] => array(3) {
    [0] => array(2) {
      [0] => string(4) "demo"
      [1] => int(8)
    }

    [1] => array(2) {
      [0] => string(4) "demo"
      [1] => int(27)
    }

    [2] => array(2) {
      [0] => string(4) "demo"
      [1] => int(40)
    }
  }
}
```

### Explanation

The first line replaces any characters in your string (called the subject argument) that match `/[a-z ]+/i` with '', essentially removing the characters. The regex matches any character (or group of characters) that is not (`^`) the letters `a-z` or a space. The `i` flag tells regex that the search should be case insensitive (This saves us from writing `a-zA-Z`).

The next line uses [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) to match the word 'demo'. However, you could substitute in any word.

### New Regex Techniques

- [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/preg-replace)
- [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/preg-match-all)
- [Word Boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)
- [Negated Character Classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated)

Comment: @pcdhan Let us know if you need any help with the implementation.

Comment: successfully implemented, again thanks a lot, it really helped me.

Comment: @pcdhan Any time. If this answered your question you should mark it as solved by clicking the checkmark next to it.

Answer (score 1):

```
/\b[^a-z]*d[^a-z]*e[^a-z]*m[^a-z]*o[^a-z]*\b/i
```

Matches anything but a-z between the demo characters

Comment: thanks @flec,  the `$input` can be max. of 15 chars  in length.

Comment: Use `strlen()` to check the lenght afterwards

Answer (score 0):

Probably not efficient; But you could use this:

`/(.*)d(.*)e(.*)m(.*)o(.*)/i`

That would match anything.